# Ternary operator behaviour in Sysout

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have a below code :

```
boolean prime = true;
System.out.println("Number is"+ prime ? "prime" : "not prime" );
```

The above code is giving compile time error.
When i modify it to :

```
System.out.println("Number is"+ prime==true ? "prime" : "not prime" );
```

It says that "Incompatible operand type : String and Boolean".
When I modify it as

```
System.out.println(prime? "prime" : "not prime" );
```

OR

```
System.out.println(prime==true? "prime" : "not prime" );
```

It works perfectly. 
What is the reason behind this behavior. Does it treat prime as a String object in Sysout? When I am using any other string in Sysout it doesnot work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at operator precedence:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

```
System.out.println("Number is"+ (prime ? "prime" : "not prime") );
```

Ternary operator has one of the lowest precedence, so it will behave in your case as follows:

```
System.out.println(("Number is"+ prime) ? "prime" : "not prime" );
```

This is surely not what you want